# Confused about rich framework to be used with spring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, rich-internet-application

my requirement is to develop rich web applications quickly and easily, and the framework must be easy/compatible with spring something like IceFaces

i am confused about IceFaces/PrimeFaces, or use jsp with YUI/DWR

please advise me.

Comment: "confused about rich frameworks"...yeah...just like everyone else

Comment: i added a specific requirement, so that the question will be limited.

Comment: i am interested in answer too...just wanted to tell how obiquitious this issue is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote Spring integration with JSF 2.1 + RichFaces 4. it works not bad, if you are searching for rapid rich client implementation it might be good choice though.

You can see basic tutorial how it works:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/

Comment: i am interested about the webflow configuration of above sample

Comment: Look at the othe examples form this page, this is very simple.

Comment: I agree , have used JSF (ICE Faces) in the past, if you are looking for Rapid development of Rich Web apps, its a good option

Answer (score 2):

SpringSource suggests PrimeFaces officially.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?98040-Which-jsf-2-component-library-to-use

Answer (score 1):

ZK is a good solution and has good integration with spring

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is not really PrimeFaces vs IceFaces (both JSF), but JSF vs YUI (or any other rich client framework), then the question comes down to: whatever makes sense for you.  See my answer here: [Spring MVC, what view components to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470699/spring-mvc-what-view-components-to-use/7487350#7487350).

Answer (score 1):

Incase you are open to options other than "IceFaces/PrimeFaces, or use jsp with YUI/DWR"

Take a look at Spring Roo and GWT combination

It is geared for rapid development, with a lot of emphasis on template based code generation. GWT is a very powerful framework when it comes to developing Rich Applications.